# How to quarter a webGL canvas crossed like it?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webgl

I'm newbie of the WebGL.

I can make canvas and I can draw the cube on the canvas.
[image]

This is example of drawing cube and tetrahedron on one canvas.
Expend this way, I want to make it like under image.
My first idea is to divide one canvas, and Second idea is make four canvas.
What is the better way?

[image]

Comment: That's all up to you. I would probably just use one canvas and [change the viewport](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/viewport) for each different camera angle. Multiple canvases would work fine as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide the canvas using the scissor and viewport commands

```
// turn on the scissor test
gl.enable(gl.SCISSOR_TEST);

var width = gl.canvas.width;
var height = gl.canvas.height;

for (var y = 0; y < 2; ++y) {
  for (var x = 0; x < 2; ++x) {

     // set both the scissor (which clips pixels)
     // and the viewport (which sets the clip space -> pixel space conversion);
     gl.scissor(x * width / 2, y * height / 2, width / 2, height / 2);
     gl.viewport(x * width / 2, y * height / 2, width / 2, height / 2); 

     ...
     draw your scene here
     ...
  }
}
```